# Как объединить изображения (кадры) в один avi-файл программным путем?

Tags: изображения, видео, directshow, c++

У нас есть набор картинок (pic1.png, pic2.png, ..., picN.png).
Надо их объединить (монтировать) в один файл типа avi, т.е. создать видео с последовательным набором этих картинок.

Какую библиотеку юзать для работы с видеокартинками?
DirectShow подойдет или нет?
В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под линукс я бы взял [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (а он есть и под винду) и умеет преобразовывать последовательность картинок в видео. Либо [mencoder/ffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/). Примеры легко гуглятся.
Если для видео использовать [mjpeg](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MJPEG), то все кодирование в принципе будет сводиться к переводу png->jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще DS тут можно использовать. Нужно только правильные кодеки подобрать. И все будет в порядке. В качестве примера можно предложить исходники virtualdub. Это редактор для видео. И он умеет перегонять видео из одного формата в другой. Набор картинок - это тоже по сути формат видео.

Comment: VirtualDub это не про DirectShow, а скорее про Video for Windows + собственная реализация формата.

Comment: В любом случае, VD - хороший пример программы работы с кодеками =)